# WPF ItemsControl Access Control in ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl with a simple item template like this:

```
<ItemsControl x:Uid="itemsControlMarketingText" x:Name="itemsControlMarketingText">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="dataTemplateMarketingText">
            <BulletDecorator x:Uid="bdMarketingTextBullet" x:Name="bdMarketingTextBullet" Width="Auto" >
                <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <Ellipse Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Black" Margin="8,0,0,0"></Ellipse>
                </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <TextBlock x:Uid="tbMarketingTextItem" x:Name="tbMarketingTextItem" Text="{Binding}" ></TextBlock>
            </BulletDecorator>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I'd like to set the Style of the tbMarketingTextItem in the code behind, so it applies to all textblocks that get created when the list is populated. So basically the same as if I had a Style property on the textblock like

```
<Style="{DynamicResource BaseTextBlockMarketingText}"
```

The problem is for this particular application, it is doing some stuff to merge different style sheets and applying styles in the code-behind. Is there a way I can get the control from the data template to apply the style to? I suspect I have to use the "FindName" method somehow, but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `FindResource()` to get a Style already defined as a resource, and then merge setters and so on into it from wherever you're getting them.

This won't work if you need to do it after the style has first been used. The alternate methods below will work in that case.

```
var btnStyle = FindResource("BaseTextBlockMarketingText") as Style;

//  Contrived example
btnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.YellowGreen));
```

Or replace it. This will work even if the style's been used already, because you're not altering the used Style object.

```
var btnStyle = new Style();

//  Contrived example
btnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.YellowGreen));

this.Resources["BaseTextBlockMarketingText"] = btnStyle;
```

XAML

```
<Style 
    x:Key="BaseTextBlockMarketingText" 
    TargetType="Button" 
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"
    />
```

...

```
<Button
    Style="{DynamicResource BaseTextBlockMarketingText}"
    />
```

### Alternate Solution

Make the button style a property of the view. Window, UserControl, doesn't matter. My XAML below will assume it's a Window, but it really doesn't matter.

This lets us replace the style rather than altering an existing style instance.

```
#region ButtonStyle Property
public Style ButtonStyle
{
    get { return (Style)GetValue(ButtonStyleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ButtonStyleProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonStyleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ButtonStyle), typeof(Style), typeof(MainWindow),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));
#endregion ButtonStyle Property
```

Initialize it however you like. For testing purposes, I just created a quickie in the view constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var style = new Style(typeof(Button), FindResource(typeof(Button)) as Style);

    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.LightSkyBlue));

    ButtonStyle = style;
}
```

And use it like so. The `AncestorType` parameter here is the only place where it matters that `ButtonStyle` is a property of a Window in particular:

```
<Button
    Style="{Binding ButtonStyle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
    />
```

It *could* be a viewmodel property instead, but a `Style` really should be part of the view.